# For loop help me

Tags: for-loop

```
word = {}
a = input('love: ').split()

for line in open('emotion.txt'):
  love, trust = line.split(',')
  word[love]=trust

for i in a:  

  print(word[i])
```

Hello, I'm trying to make outcome in line when I print it.
but I don't know how to get it printed in one line at last.
this code's current outcome is.

```
I 
love
you
```

but I wanna make it as

```
I love you
```

thank you

Comment: Not that you actually bothered to mention the programming language you're using, but I'd guess you wanted https://stackoverflow.com/q/493386/3001761. Please do research before asking in the future.

Comment: What language is this? Please edit your question to add it as a tag. And please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space)

Comment: It's python and what more information you need for me to make good question?

Comment: jonrsharpe/ And of course I did research, but range is not a matter. DId you even see my code?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Put a comma ',' after print statement. This wll solve your issue

```
word = {}
a = input('love: ').split()

for line in open('emotion.txt'):
  love, trust = line.split(',')
  word[love]=trust

for i in a:  
  print(word[i]),
```